# Error 500 Internal Server en Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, backend, postman, server, error500

Tengo un problema cuando hago una request en Postman de una API, no me salta ningún problema pero me dice error 500 y no tengo respuesta, el arreglo que mando vuelve vacío. Ya probé todo no se que mas puede ser. Estoy haciendo una app en Nodejs con base da datos en MongoDB. Les dejo el código:

Esta es la request que mando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la respuesta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No me muestra ningún error en la consola pero no llega nada

Esta es la consola de VSC
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Este es la app.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require("dotenv/config");
const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('./helpers/error-handler');

app.use(cors());

app.options('*', cors());

//middleware 
app.use(express.json());  
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(authJwt()); 
app.use(errorHandler); //Manejo de errores de autenticación
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
    


//routes
const categoriesRoutes = require('./routes/categories');
const productsRoutes = require('./routes/products');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/orders');



const api = process.env.API_URL;


app.use(`${api}/categories`, categoriesRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/users`, usersRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/orders`, ordersRoutes);



//Database conexion 
//user: e-shop  password: 12345M
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING , {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName: 'eshop-database'
}) 
.then( () => {
console.log('Database connection is ready!')
})
.catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

//empezando el servidor
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server is running http://localhost:3000");
});
```

ruta de productos: Products.js

```
const {Product} = require('../models/product');
const express = require('express');
const { Category } = require('../models/category');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');

//CARGA DE IMAGENES
//Datos sacados de la libreria npm multer, disk, para no tener problemas con nombres e imagenes
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads') //direccion donde van a estar las imagenes
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-'); //forma de nombrar el archivo
        cb(null, fileName + '-' + Date.now()) //date.now para que el nombre de file sea unico
    }
})
const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage })

//GET REQUEST: recibe
router.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {  //METODO PARA MOSTRAR UN PRODUCTO

    let filter = {};
    if(req.query.categories){
        filter = {category: req.query.categories.split(',')}
    }

    const productList = await Product.find(filter).populate('category');  //.select('name image -_id');  :nos va a mostrar solo el nombre e imagen y con el menos no nos muestra el id

    if(!productList){
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    }
    
    res.send(productList);
});

//GET REQUEST
//obtener un producto y una lista de productos por su id REST API
router.get(`/:id`, async (req, res) => {  //METODO PARA MOSTRAR UN PRODUCTO
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).populate('category'); //el populate se utiliza para relacionar dos tablas de mongo db

    if(!product){
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    }
    
    res.send(product);
});

//POST REQUEST //envio
router.post(`/`, uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) => {  //METODO PARA ENVIAR DESDE EL FRONT UN PRODUCTO
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid category!')

    const fileName = req.file.fileName; //este nombre va a venir de: cb(null, fileName + '-' + Date.now())
    //creamos la base de la direccion para la imagen: http://localhost:3000/public/uploads
    //protocol me da el http
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;

    const product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,       //req = requiere
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,  // ej direccion de imagen: "http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/image-232125212.jpeg" 
        brand: req.body.brand, 
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured
    })
    product = await product.save();

    if (!product) return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be created');

    res.send(product);
});

//Actualizar un producto
//put request
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)){  //si el id es valido continua si no no
        res.status(400).send('Invalid product ID!')
    }  
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid category!')

    const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,       //req = requiere
        image: req.body.image,
        brand: req.body.brand,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured
        },
        {new: true}
    )
    if(!product){    //chequeo si no hay categoria creada y envio el error
        return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be updated!');
    }

    res.send(product);  //si esta creada la categoria la devuelvo si no manda el erro de arriba
})

//Borrar los productos por el id
//Delete request
// api/v1/products/idSeleccionado
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Category.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then(product => {  //llamamos una promesa
        if(product){  //si encontras la producto con ese id
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message:'The product is deleted!'})
        }else{ //si no encuentra producto con ese id
            return res.status(404).json({success: false, message:'Product not found!'})
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err})
    })
})

//Get products count
//Obtener recuentos de productos con fines estadísticos
router.get(`/get/count`, async (req, res) => {  //METODO PARA MOSTRAR UN PRODUCTO
    const productCount = await Product.countDocuments((count) => count); //recibo la cantidad y me devuelve la cantidad

    if(!productCount){
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    }
    
    res.send({
        productCount: productCount
    });
});  

//Get request: Featured products
//obtener productos destacados
router.get(`/get/featured/:count`, async (req, res) => {  
    const count = req.params.count ? req.params.count: 0;
    const products = await Product.find({isFeatured: true}).limit(+count); //le ponemos el + para transformar count es un Number, si no es un string

    if(!products){
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    }
    
    res.send(products);
});  
module.exports = router;
```

Si falta algún dato lo subo no se que mas subir. Gracias

Comment: Tal vez el error está en el middleware de Multer, has depurado eso?

Comment: No creo porque el error está desde antes de que agregue multer al proyecto, la verdad no se pero pruebo igual